# wait() and notify() methods

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have two classes First and Second. In class First I just run two threads. Class Second has two methods, one for changing static variable array, and one for reading array after changing. I want to do this whit wait and notify.

```
class First{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Second s1 = new Second(1);
    Second s2 = new Second(2);
    s1.start();
    s2.start();
  }
}

    class Second extends Thread{
      private static int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
      private int number;

      Second(int number){
        this.number = number;
      }

      public void run(){
        change();
        System.out.println("Out of change: " + getName());
        read();
      }

      public synchronized void change(){
        if(array[0] != 1)
          return;

        System.out.println("Change: " + getName());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          array[0] += i; 
        notify();
      }

      public synchronized void read(){
          try{
          System.out.println("Waiting for change:" + getName());
          wait();
          }
          catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
          }
        System.out.println("Score: " + array[0]);
      }

}
```

I'm getting IllegalMonitorException. I want to one thread change array[0] to 46 and then read array[0] in both threads. How to solve that problem? Do I must use lock variable?

Comment: Change `read()` to a synchronized method. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Please don't try to restate the errors you get; copy and paste the stack trace.

Comment: @chrylis is right. I had to dig through your code to see where your call to `wait()` is.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `wait`, you must call it from a synchronized method. You are calling it from a non-synchronized method. Making `read` synchronized will solve the problem.

By the way, it would be a better idea to lock the array instead of the thread, because that is where control to the data is required. You can do that by making your methods unsynchronized, then putting all the code inside this:

```
synchronized(array) {
    // put all the code here
}
```

Then change calls to `wait` and `notify` to `array.wait` and `array.notify`.

Comment: ok, I change that and this is output:
Change: Thread-3
Out of change: Thread-3
Waiting for change:Thread-3
Change: Thread-4
Out of change: Thread-4
Waiting for change:Thread-4   
Where is a resulte?

Comment: @StrahinjaZeljic Please don't comment your output. Instead, edit your post, explain what you tried, and put the output there.

Comment: Your `notify` is lost, because it happens before a `wait`. If you tell me exactly what you are trying to achieve, I can write your code for you, or you can research threads a little bit more.

Comment: I want to one thread change array[0] to 46 and then read array[0] in both threads. But, I want do that without using lock. And with using methods change and read.

Comment: @StrahinjaZeljic I need a few more details.

Comment: @tbodt I think you're right. This is simple example, but i need to understand that I would do much more complicated problem. I dont know what else do you need. One thread must to change array[][]. other thread must to read that.

Comment: As I can't understand exactly what you are asking, I think you should look at the [Java Tutorial on Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for the answers to all of your threading questions.

Comment: OK, thanks. I dont think I will find how threads behave whit static variable. that is my problem, I have static variable and I need to change that variable in many threads.

Comment: @StrahinjaZeljic You don't use a static variable. You use an object that is referenced in all the threads.

Comment: I use a reference to a shared variable. in all threads that's the same object

Comment: @StrahinjaZeljic Use the `volatile` modifier on members that are meant to be modified on multiple threads.

Comment: @tbodt That's an old bug in Java 1.4, fixed in Java 5.